# Check if the User who fired the RemoteEvent is in Group then Continue

Tags: roblox

I want to create an "Admin Panel" for my Roblox Game.

As already in the title saying, If a RemoteEvent is fired to do a certain thing, I want to check if the User is in the Provided GroupId and then only Continue. If the user is not in the group who fired the RemoteEvent/Executed the Command, then cancel the Request or do nothing.

^ I am doing it to prevent Exploiters Firing RemoteEvents and abuse the Commands even tho they are not an Admin/In the Group

Is there any way to do it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a player is in a certain group using [`Player:isInGroup(GroupID)`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/IsInGroup).

---

```lua
local RemoteEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent"); -- This shall be your RemoteEvent.

RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    if not player:IsInGroup(123456) then return false end; -- If the player is not in the group, the function will not continue.

    -- Your code here.
end)
```

Comment: Doesn't it check if the Target player (Which will be taken action on by a command) is in the group? If the Target player is not in the group the action will not be taken. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No. No matter how many arguments you pass to the RemoteEvent, the first will always the be player which fired it.